# Downgrade to DifferentialEquations v6.0 in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-pkg

How can I downgrade the DifferentialEquations package to version 6.0 (or earlier), such that all depending packages also downgrade if they require a version that is > 6.0?

Answer (score 6):

Just ask the package manager to do so with an `add DifferentialEquations@v6.0` at the `pkg>` prompt.  It'll automatically handle the dependencies. Remember, you can enter the package manager prompt by typing `]` at the REPL. Here's an example from me doing so in an active project of mine with lots of dependencies installed:

```
(LocalEnvironment) pkg> status
Project LocalEnvironment v0.1.9
Status `~/Projects/LocalEnvironment/Project.toml`
  [6e4b80f9] BenchmarkTools v0.5.0
  [a134a8b2] BlackBoxOptim v0.5.0
  [336ed68f] CSV v0.8.2
  [be33ccc6] CUDAnative v3.2.0
  [3a865a2d] CuArrays v2.2.2
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.22.4
  [071ae1c0] DiffEqGPU v1.3.0
  [0c46a032] DifferentialEquations v6.16.0
  [f6369f11] ForwardDiff v0.10.15
  [0c68f7d7] GPUArrays v3.4.1
  [033835bb] JLD2 v0.3.2
  [2ee39098] LabelledArrays v1.4.0
  [961ee093] ModelingToolkit v3.20.1
  [429524aa] Optim v1.2.3
  [1dea7af3] OrdinaryDiffEq v5.42.3
  [f3b207a7] StatsPlots v0.14.17
  [9672c7b4] SteadyStateDiffEq v1.6.0
  [c3572dad] Sundials v4.2.6
  [6fc51010] Surrogates v1.5.0
  [10745b16] Statistics

(LocalEnvironment) pkg> add DifferentialEquations@v6.0
  Resolving package versions...
Updating `~/Projects/LocalEnvironment/Project.toml`
  [be33ccc6] ↓ CUDAnative v3.2.0 ⇒ v2.10.2
  [3a865a2d] ↓ CuArrays v2.2.2 ⇒ v1.7.3
  [a93c6f00] ↓ DataFrames v0.22.4 ⇒ v0.21.8
  [071ae1c0] ↓ DiffEqGPU v1.3.0 ⇒ v0.3.0
  [0c46a032] ↓ DifferentialEquations v6.16.0 ⇒ v6.0.0
  [0c68f7d7] ↓ GPUArrays v3.4.1 ⇒ v2.0.1
  [033835bb] ↓ JLD2 v0.3.2 ⇒ v0.1.14
  [2ee39098] ↓ LabelledArrays v1.4.0 ⇒ v1.1.0
  [961ee093] ↓ ModelingToolkit v3.20.1 ⇒ v0.8.0
  [429524aa] ↓ Optim v1.2.3 ⇒ v0.20.1
  [1dea7af3] ↓ OrdinaryDiffEq v5.42.3 ⇒ v5.13.0
  [f3b207a7] ↓ StatsPlots v0.14.17 ⇒ v0.14.5
  [9672c7b4] ↓ SteadyStateDiffEq v1.6.0 ⇒ v1.5.0
  [c3572dad] ↓ Sundials v4.2.6 ⇒ v3.7.0
Updating `~/Projects/Pfizer/LeucineModel/Manifest.toml`
  [c3fe647b] - AbstractAlgebra v0.11.2
  [4fba245c] ↓ ArrayInterface v2.14.17 ⇒ v0.1.1
  [4c555306] ↓ ArrayLayouts v0.3.8 ⇒ v0.1.5
  [aae01518] ↓ BandedMatrices v0.15.15 ⇒ v0.14.3
  [9e28174c] + BinDeps v1.0.2
  [8e7c35d0] ↓ BlockArrays v0.12.11 ⇒ v0.10.2
  [ffab5731] + BlockBandedMatrices v0.6.0
  [764a87c0] ↓ BoundaryValueDiffEq v2.7.1 ⇒ v2.3.0
  [6e34b625] - Bzip2_jll v1.0.6+5
  [fa961155] ↓ CEnum v0.3.0 ⇒ v0.2.0
  [3895d2a7] ↓ CUDAapi v4.0.0 ⇒ v3.1.0
  [c5f51814] ↓ CUDAdrv v6.3.0 ⇒ v6.0.0
  [be33ccc6] ↓ CUDAnative v3.2.0 ⇒ v2.10.2
  [83423d85] - Cairo_jll v1.16.0+6
  [49dc2e85] + Calculus v0.5.1
  [324d7699] ↓ CategoricalArrays v0.9.0 ⇒ v0.8.3
  [082447d4] - ChainRules v0.6.5
  [d360d2e6] - ChainRulesCore v0.8.1
  [8bab3169] + ChunkedArrays v0.1.1
  [aaaa29a8] ↓ Clustering v0.14.2 ⇒ v0.13.5
  [da1fd8a2] - CodeTracking v1.0.5
  [944b1d66] ↓ CodecZlib v0.7.0 ⇒ v0.6.0
  [35d6a980] - ColorSchemes v3.10.2
  [3da002f7] ↓ ColorTypes v0.10.9 ⇒ v0.9.1
  [5ae59095] ↓ Colors v0.12.6 ⇒ v0.11.2
  [34da2185] ↓ Compat v3.25.0 ⇒ v2.2.1
  [88cd18e8] - ConsoleProgressMonitor v0.1.2
  [187b0558] - ConstructionBase v1.0.0
  [a8cc5b0e] - Crayons v4.0.4
  [f68482b8] - Cthulhu v1.6.1
  [3a865a2d] ↓ CuArrays v2.2.2 ⇒ v1.7.3
  [a93c6f00] ↓ DataFrames v0.22.4 ⇒ v0.21.8
  [bcd4f6db] ↓ DelayDiffEq v5.24.1 ⇒ v5.12.0
  [2b5f629d] ↓ DiffEqBase v6.44.3 ⇒ v5.16.5
  [459566f4] ↓ DiffEqCallbacks v2.13.5 ⇒ v2.7.0
  [01453d9d] + DiffEqDiffTools v0.14.0
  [5a0ffddc] ↓ DiffEqFinancial v2.4.0 ⇒ v2.1.0
  [071ae1c0] ↓ DiffEqGPU v1.3.0 ⇒ v0.3.0
  [c894b116] ↓ DiffEqJump v6.10.0 ⇒ v6.2.2
  [78ddff82] + DiffEqMonteCarlo v0.15.1
  [77a26b50] ↓ DiffEqNoiseProcess v5.5.1 ⇒ v3.3.1
  [9fdde737] + DiffEqOperators v3.5.0
  [34035eb4] + DiffEqPDEBase v0.4.0
  [055956cb] ↓ DiffEqPhysics v3.9.0 ⇒ v3.2.0
  [b552c78f] ↓ DiffRules v1.0.2 ⇒ v0.1.0
  [0c46a032] ↓ DifferentialEquations v6.16.0 ⇒ v6.0.0
  [c619ae07] ↓ DimensionalPlotRecipes v1.2.0 ⇒ v0.2.0
  [b4f34e82] ↓ Distances v0.9.2 ⇒ v0.8.2
  [31c24e10] ↓ Distributions v0.23.8 ⇒ v0.21.12
  [5ae413db] - EarCut_jll v2.1.5+1
  [da5c29d0] + EllipsisNotation v0.4.0
  [2e619515] - Expat_jll v2.2.7+6
  [d4d017d3] ↓ ExponentialUtilities v1.8.0 ⇒ v1.6.0
  [e2ba6199] - ExprTools v0.1.3
  [c87230d0] ↓ FFMPEG v0.4.0 ⇒ v0.2.4
  [b22a6f82] - FFMPEG_jll v4.3.1+4
  [9aa1b823] - FastClosures v0.3.2
  [5789e2e9] + FileIO v1.4.5
  [6a86dc24] - FiniteDiff v2.7.2
  [53c48c17] ↓ FixedPointNumbers v0.8.4 ⇒ v0.6.1
  [587475ba] ↓ Flux v0.10.4 ⇒ v0.10.3
  [1eca21be] - FoldingTrees v1.0.1
  [a3f928ae] - Fontconfig_jll v2.13.1+14
  [59287772] - Formatting v0.4.2
  [d7e528f0] - FreeType2_jll v2.10.1+5
  [559328eb] - FriBidi_jll v1.0.5+6
  [0656b61e] - GLFW_jll v3.3.2+1
  [0c68f7d7] ↓ GPUArrays v3.4.1 ⇒ v2.0.1
  [61eb1bfa] - GPUCompiler v0.2.0
  [28b8d3ca] ↓ GR v0.53.0 ⇒ v0.44.92
  [d2c73de3] - GR_jll v0.53.0+0
  [01680d73] ↓ GenericSVD v0.3.0 ⇒ v0.2.2
  [5c1252a2] - GeometryBasics v0.3.8
  [4d00f742] + GeometryTypes v0.7.10
  [78b55507] - Gettext_jll v0.20.1+7
  [7746bdde] - Glib_jll v2.59.0+4
  [cd3eb016] - HTTP v0.8.19
  [7869d1d1] ↓ IRTools v0.4.2 ⇒ v0.3.3
  [615f187c] - IfElse v0.1.0
  [83e8ac13] - IniFile v0.5.0
  [a98d9a8b] ↓ Interpolations v0.13.1 ⇒ v0.12.10
  [c8e1da08] - IterTools v1.3.0
  [033835bb] ↓ JLD2 v0.3.2 ⇒ v0.1.14
  [aacddb02] - JpegTurbo_jll v2.0.1+3
  [5ab0869b] ↓ KernelDensity v0.6.2 ⇒ v0.5.1
  [c1c5ebd0] - LAME_jll v3.100.0+3
  [dd4b983a] - LZO_jll v2.10.0+3
  [b964fa9f] - LaTeXStrings v1.2.0
  [2ee39098] ↓ LabelledArrays v1.4.0 ⇒ v1.1.0
  [23fbe1c1] - Latexify v0.14.7
  [1d6d02ad] - LeftChildRightSiblingTrees v0.1.2
  [dd192d2f] - LibVPX_jll v1.9.0+1
  [e9f186c6] - Libffi_jll v3.2.1+4
  [d4300ac3] - Libgcrypt_jll v1.8.5+4
  [7e76a0d4] - Libglvnd_jll v1.3.0+3
  [7add5ba3] - Libgpg_error_jll v1.36.0+3
  [94ce4f54] - Libiconv_jll v1.16.0+7
  [4b2f31a3] - Libmount_jll v2.34.0+3
  [89763e89] - Libtiff_jll v4.1.0+2
  [38a345b3] - Libuuid_jll v2.34.0+7
  [e6f89c97] - LoggingExtras v0.4.4
  [d00139f3] - METIS_jll v5.1.0+5
  [a3b82374] + MatrixFactorizations v0.2.1
  [739be429] - MbedTLS v1.0.3
  [c8ffd9c3] - MbedTLS_jll v2.16.8+1
  [961ee093] ↓ ModelingToolkit v3.20.1 ⇒ v0.8.0
  [f9640e96] ↓ MultiScaleArrays v1.8.1 ⇒ v1.5.0
  [d41bc354] ↓ NLSolversBase v7.7.1 ⇒ v7.5.0
  [b8a86587] ↓ NearestNeighbors v0.4.8 ⇒ v0.4.4
  [e7412a2a] - Ogg_jll v1.3.4+2
  [458c3c95] - OpenSSL_jll v1.1.1+6
  [efe28fd5] - OpenSpecFun_jll v0.5.3+4
  [429524aa] ↓ Optim v1.2.3 ⇒ v0.20.1
  [91d4177d] - Opus_jll v1.3.1+3
  [1dea7af3] ↓ OrdinaryDiffEq v5.42.3 ⇒ v5.13.0
  [2f80f16e] - PCRE_jll v8.42.0+4
  [90014a1f] ↓ PDMats v0.10.1 ⇒ v0.9.12
  [65888b18] - ParameterizedFunctions v5.6.0
  [d96e819e] ↓ Parameters v0.12.2 ⇒ v0.11.0
  [30392449] - Pixman_jll v0.40.0+0
  [ccf2f8ad] ↓ PlotThemes v2.0.0 ⇒ v1.0.3
  [995b91a9] ↓ PlotUtils v1.0.10 ⇒ v0.6.5
  [91a5bcdd] ↓ Plots v1.10.2 ⇒ v0.28.4
  [8d666b04] ↓ PolyChaos v0.2.3 ⇒ v0.2.1
  [08abe8d2] - PrettyTables v0.11.0
  [33c8b6b6] - ProgressLogging v0.1.4
  [92933f4c] - ProgressMeter v1.4.1
  [ede63266] - Qt_jll v5.15.2+1
  [74087812] - Random123 v1.3.1
  [fb686558] - RandomExtensions v0.4.3
  [3cdcf5f2] ↓ RecipesBase v1.1.1 ⇒ v0.7.0
  [01d81517] - RecipesPipeline v0.2.1
  [731186ca] ↓ RecursiveArrayTools v2.10.0 ⇒ v0.20.0
  [ae029012] ↓ Requires v1.1.2 ⇒ v0.5.2
  [f2b01f46] ↓ Roots v1.0.7 ⇒ v0.8.4
  [1bc83da4] - SafeTestsets v0.0.1
  [6c6a2e73] - Scratch v1.0.3
  [47a9eef4] ↓ SparseDiffTools v1.12.0 ⇒ v0.6.0
  [276daf66] ↓ SpecialFunctions v0.10.3 ⇒ v0.8.0
  [90137ffa] ↓ StaticArrays v0.12.5 ⇒ v0.11.1
  [2913bbd2] ↓ StatsBase v0.33.2 ⇒ v0.32.2
  [f3b207a7] ↓ StatsPlots v0.14.17 ⇒ v0.14.5
  [9672c7b4] ↓ SteadyStateDiffEq v1.6.0 ⇒ v1.5.0
  [8188c328] ↓ Stheno v0.6.6 ⇒ v0.6.1
  [789caeaf] ↓ StochasticDiffEq v6.25.0 ⇒ v6.7.0
  [09ab397b] - StructArrays v0.4.4
  [bea87d4a] - SuiteSparse_jll v5.4.0+9
  [c3572dad] ↓ Sundials v4.2.6 ⇒ v3.7.0
  [fb77eaff] - Sundials_jll v5.2.0+1
  [d1185830] - SymbolicUtils v0.5.2
  [ab02a1b2] ↓ TableOperations v0.3.0 ⇒ v0.2.1
  [5d786b92] - TerminalLoggers v0.1.3
  [30578b45] + URIParser v0.4.1
  [1986cc42] - Unitful v1.5.0
  [0e69188a] + VectorizedRoutines v0.1.0
  [a2964d1f] - Wayland_jll v1.17.0+4
  [2381bf8a] - Wayland_protocols_jll v1.18.0+4
  [02c8fc9c] - XML2_jll v2.9.10+3
  [aed1982a] - XSLT_jll v1.1.33+4
  [4f6342f7] - Xorg_libX11_jll v1.6.9+4
  [0c0b7dd1] - Xorg_libXau_jll v1.0.9+4
  [935fb764] - Xorg_libXcursor_jll v1.2.0+4
  [a3789734] - Xorg_libXdmcp_jll v1.1.3+4
  [1082639a] - Xorg_libXext_jll v1.3.4+4
  [d091e8ba] - Xorg_libXfixes_jll v5.0.3+4
  [a51aa0fd] - Xorg_libXi_jll v1.7.10+4
  [d1454406] - Xorg_libXinerama_jll v1.1.4+4
  [ec84b674] - Xorg_libXrandr_jll v1.5.2+4
  [ea2f1a96] - Xorg_libXrender_jll v0.9.10+4
  [14d82f49] - Xorg_libpthread_stubs_jll v0.1.0+3
  [c7cfdc94] - Xorg_libxcb_jll v1.13.0+3
  [cc61e674] - Xorg_libxkbfile_jll v1.1.0+4
  [12413925] - Xorg_xcb_util_image_jll v0.4.0+1
  [2def613f] - Xorg_xcb_util_jll v0.4.0+1
  [975044d2] - Xorg_xcb_util_keysyms_jll v0.4.0+1
  [0d47668e] - Xorg_xcb_util_renderutil_jll v0.3.9+1
  [c22f9ab0] - Xorg_xcb_util_wm_jll v0.4.1+1
  [35661453] - Xorg_xkbcomp_jll v1.4.2+4
  [33bec58e] - Xorg_xkeyboard_config_jll v2.27.0+4
  [c5fb5394] - Xorg_xtrans_jll v1.4.0+3
  [3161d3a3] - Zstd_jll v1.4.5+2
  [e88e6eb3] ↓ Zygote v0.4.22 ⇒ v0.4.20
  [0ac62f75] - libass_jll v0.14.0+4
  [f638f0a6] - libfdk_aac_jll v0.1.6+4
  [b53b4c65] - libpng_jll v1.6.37+6
  [f27f6e37] - libvorbis_jll v1.3.6+6
  [1270edf5] - x264_jll v2020.7.14+2
  [dfaa095f] - x265_jll v3.0.0+3
  [d8fb68d0] - xkbcommon_jll v0.9.1+5
```